# VBA with sql query - optimization

Tags: sql, vba, excel

All,

I have two tabels: Cases(IdCase, Name) and Alerts(IdAlert, refIdCase, Profile).
One case can have multiple alerts connected by refIdCase.
I'm dipslaying the list in VBA listbox which shows case name and profiles assigned to this case.

Firstly I download 50 cases. Then for each recordset I'm finding profile names. Unfortunately it takes some time :( Is there any faster way to achieve that?

`set rsCases = cn.Execute("SELECT TOP 50 * FROM Cases")
Do Until rsCases.EOF
  Set rsProfiles = cn.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT TOP 50 Profile FROM Alert WHERE refIdCase = " & rsCases.Fields("IdCase").value & ";")
rsCases.movenext`

UPDATE: I believe the problem is with our connection to sql server. We are located in Poland and the server is in North America. I performed the same action from computer located in NA and it took only 4 sec, but here from Poland it takes around 45 sec.

Thank you,
TJ

Comment: Interesting solution - what is the **business requirement** being addressed by this (non-performant) solution?

Comment: 1) Where are the tables located -- in an Access database, or in some other RDBMS? Do you have some kind of index on the Alerts table? 2) Do you need exactly 50 records from the subquery? If it returns more is that also acceptable?

Comment: I have created this macro in outlook. We have monitoring team which reacts on alerts. This macro help them (creating escalation email  based on alert body, creating ticket in external system etc.). Additionally we would like to keep history of actions in SQL. Whenever user runs macro, this code checks history and displays cases with assigned alerts. It takes about 1 sec to search profiles for each case. About 1 minute to display history. It is a little bit to long :/

Comment: Zev: Database is located on SQL server. It can return more, no problem with that. I have created index now, but it won't help or i'm doing it wrong: CREATE INDEX refIdCase_index
ON Alert (refIdCase)

Comment: On a side not it might be worth pointing out that using TOP without an ORDER BY clause means the rows returned will be random which might not be what you actually want.

Comment: JPW: thanks for comment. I tried to order by start time. I cut this code/part for this example. My bad. But still it is taking the same time.

Comment: The main problem is that you are doing this Case by Case. I would suggest that you add a stored procedure to the SQL database that returns a single table with the Case columns joined with the the required Alert columns. Then get the results from this stored procedure from VBA.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sending 51 requests to the database. Send 1:

```
set rstCases = cn.Execute("SELECT c.IdCase, c.Name, a.IdAlert, a.Profile
                           FROM   Cases c
                                  INNER JOIN
                                  (SELECT TOP 50 IdAlert, Profile
                                   FROM   Alerts
                                   ORDER BY ???) a
                                  ON c.IdCase=a.refIdCase
                           ORDER BY ???")
```

(Linebreaks are for clarity - don't put then in your code)